# Android raw surface buffer (winapi32 SetDIBits equivalent)

Tags: android, graphics

I need access to a raw surface buffer (app surface, not device framebuffer) where I can draw bits with memory moving instructions from a native thread. Something like SetDIBits or SetDIBitsToDevice from Windows API but on Android device.

I guess there are several ways to do it: via OpenGL|ES, via Java... I want a short list of different ways to do that and which functions I should use (usage examples not needed).

Answer (score 0):

At the lowest level you have gralloc, but the recommended interface in recent Android releases is SurfaceTexture (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way (based on prabindh answer) is this:

```
Canvas canvas = myTextureView.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint);
myTextureView.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```